# MongoDB Aggregation "group" with "max" field within a sub-array

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Using Compass initially, I then need to convert it into the PHP library.

So far, I have a 1st stage that filters the documents on 2 fields using `$match`:

- comp.id (sub-document / array)
- playerId

Code is:
$match (from drop-down)

```
{
    "comp.id" : ObjectId('607019361c071256e4f0d0d5'),
    "playerId" : "609d0993906429612483cea0"
}
```

This returns 2 documents.

The document has a sub-array `holes`, for the holes played in a round of golf. This sub-array has fields (among others):

- holes.no
- holes.par
- holes.grossScore
- holes.nettPoints

So each round has 1 document, with a `holes` sub-array of (typically) 18 array elements (holes), or 9 for half-round. A player will play each round multiple times - hence multiple documents.

I would like to find the highest `holes.nettPoints` across the documents. I think I need to `$group` with `$max` on the `holes.nettPoints` field, so I would find the highest score for each hole across all rounds.

I have tried this, but in Compass its says its not properly formatted:
`$group` drop-down

```
{
  _id: holes.no,
  "highest":
    { $max: "$holes.nettPoints" }
}
```

"highest" can be any name I want?

EDIT FOLLOWING PROVIDED ANSWER

The answer marked as the solution was enough of a pointer for how the Aggregation Framework operates (multi-stage documents, i.e. documents as input to 1 stage become new documents as the output of that stage. And so on.

For the purposes of posterity, I ended up using the following aggregation:

```
[{$match: {
    "comp.id" : ObjectId('607019361c071256e4f0d0d5'),
    "playerId" : "609d0993906429612483cea0",
    "comp.courseId" : "608955aaabebbd503ba6e116"
}
}, {$unwind: {
  path : "$holes"
}}, {$group: {
  _id: "$holes.no",
  hole: {
    $max: "$holes"
  }
}}, {$sort: {
  "hole": 1
}}]
```

In PHP speak, it looks like:

```
    $match = [
        '$match' => [
            'comp.id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( $compId ),
            'playerId' => $playerId,
            'comp.courseId' => $courseId
        ]
    ];
    
    $unwind = [
        '$unwind' => [
            'path' => '$holes'
        ]
    ];
    
    $group = [
        '$group' => [
            '_id' => '$holes.no',
            'hole' => [
                '$max' => '$holes'
            ]
        ]
    ];
    
    $sort = [
        '$sort' => [
            'hole.no' => 1
        ]
    ];
    
    $cursor = $collection->aggregate([$match, $unwind, $group, $sort]);
```

It is not complete (looking at adding a `$sum` accumulator across the `courseId`, not individual documents), but answers the question posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` your conditions
- `$unwind` deconstruct `holes` array
- `$sort` by `nettPoints` in descending order
- `$group` by `no` and select first `holes` object

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      "comp.id": ObjectId("607019361c071256e4f0d0d5"),
      "playerId": "609d0993906429612483cea0"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$holes" },
  { $sort: { "holes.nettPoints": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$holes.no",
      highest: { $first: "$holes" }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: oh my gosh, @turivishal, what a great helper into the workings of the Aggregation Framework! I see the principles, and have been able to adjust it now I am getting an understanding of what is going on. I obviously have a bunch of further questions, but will keep to a minimum. So its basically passing full MongoDB documents between stages, which can be changed as well? I used `'$max'` instead of `'$first'`, and ideally I would also like the `'$sum'` of the `holes.nettPoints` - would this occur in the `$group` stage? Finally, how do you learn this stuff - is it just immersion & practice?!?

Comment: *would this occur in the $group stage?* yes, *how do you learn this stuff*, practice everyday different queries and using different operators from [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/).. and also there are [mongodb university free courses](https://university.mongodb.com/).

Comment: thanks again. if I append an extra field, it is being applied within each document, rather than across all returned (i.e. input) documents to the `$group` stage. If I add a second `$group` for the whole round, am I still able to access the `holes` array from previous stages?

Comment: Tested code, the `$group` command is: `$group: {
        _id: "$holes.no",
        highest: {
            $max: "$holes"
        },
        total: {
            $sum: "$holes.holeNettPoints"
        }
    }`